# How to sign a request in ruby using PKCS-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

1. Assemble the following information:

   - The full URL you wish to call, including any path and query parameters.
   - Your Consumer ID (for example, 9a4d7659-100c-4d5e-a6b0-26faad4c9132).
   - Your Base 64-encoded Private Key.
   - Your request method in all capitals (for example, GET).
2. Construct input for the signature (NOTE: The order of the parameters and the line returns \n are important to generate the signature properly):
   **the Consumer ID issued to you_** + "\n" + **the url of the call you are making** + "\n" + **the request method of the call you are making in all capitals** + "\n" + **the Epoch timestamp now (in milliseconds since Jan 01 1970 UTC)** + "\n"
3. Sign the byte array representation of this data by:
  Decoding the Base-64, PKCS-8 representation of your Private Key. Note that the key is encoded using PKCS-8. Libraries in various languages offer the ability to specify that the key is in this format and not in other conflicting formats such as PKCS-1.
  Use this byte representation of your key to sign the data using SHA-256 with RSA.
  Encode the resulting signature using Base-64.
4. Use the generated signature and the timestamp to make your API call.

Comment: What is your question - decoding the PKCS-8 representation of your private key, or signing the data using SHA-256? What have you tried? Please show your code.

Comment: I am new to ruby on rails. I am not sure how to achieve this one. Requirement from https://developer.walmart.com/#/apicenter/contentProvider#authentication